# Adding a scroll bar to MS Chart control C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

please understand that I know there are other threads concerning this issue, but my needs are different.

Basically before I seen people saying to implement a scroll bar with MSChart they use the

.Size = ...

or

.View = ...

But, this make a scroll bar automatically apprear, and this scroll bar contains a button that when clicked causes the bar to vanish, making the chart show all data, and no way of bringing back the scroll bar to the chart without restarting the app.

So I ask, please, Is there a way to incorportate a horizontal scroll bar on the X-axis of my Chart? I am needing on so that I can view my chart data on blocks of 100 second blocks.

i.e. 0 - 100, then click sroll bar will bring me to 100 - 200 block.

Thank you in advance guys!!!!! im coding in C# also

Answer (score 30):

Here's an example of what you need:
 (to try it, just create a form, add a mschart and call the following method)

```
private void FillChart()
{
    int blockSize = 100;

    // generates random data (i.e. 30 * blockSize random numbers)
    Random rand = new Random();
    var valuesArray = Enumerable.Range(0, blockSize * 30).Select(x => rand.Next(1, 10)).ToArray();

    // clear the chart
    chart1.Series.Clear();

    // fill the chart
    var series = chart1.Series.Add("My Series");
    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
    for (int i = 0; i < valuesArray.Length; i++)
        series.Points.AddXY(i, valuesArray[i]);
    var chartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea];

    // set view range to [0,max]
    chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = valuesArray.Length;

    // enable autoscroll
    chartArea.CursorX.AutoScroll = true;

    // let's zoom to [0,blockSize] (e.g. [0,100])
    chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
    chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
    int position = 0;
    int size = blockSize;
    chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(position, size);

    // disable zoom-reset button (only scrollbar's arrows are available)
    chartArea.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;

    // set scrollbar small change to blockSize (e.g. 100)
    chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = blockSize;
}
```

---

**Snapshot:**

[image: mschart zooming]

Comment: @digEmAll, the snapshot link is broken.

Comment: @Devendra: It's not a link but there's an image below... maybe your browser didn't load the image... ?

Comment: @digEmAll, the image is not visible. I tried to check the link (by editing the answer), but even this is invalid.

Comment: @digEmAll, the snapshot is visible.

Comment: @digEmAll, the image might have been blocked by the firewall at my office. :)

Comment: I can't upvote this for some reason, but thought I'd just say that this helped me solve a problem with my RangeBar chart. However, the scrollbar doesn't seem to draw correctly - it seems to be transparent instead of the usual winforms grey! Any ideas?

Comment: @Jez: Sorry, I have no idea (in particular without seeing your code). Try to post a new question showing your problem and the code to reproduce it :)

Comment: I figured this out, it was just a load of properties buried in the Axis that I needed to set that have silly default values :P

Comment: Hi @digEmAll, thanks for example code. But i have a query, what if we want to display each value of XAxis (1, 2, 3...). When i set the chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1d; in code,  it does not show the X-Axis values correctly. Any pointer on how to acheive it. Appreciate your thoughts on this

Comment: @DnshPly9: it's hard to say without looking the code... can you post your own question ?

Comment: I added `If Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum -Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum > 90 Then Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.Position = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.Position + 100 End If` To another function that adds the next set of data to keep auto-scrolling to the right as data is added.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
    if (series1.Points.Count > 2 && chartArea1.AxisX.Maximum - chartArea1.AxisX.Minimum > chartArea1.AxisX.ScaleView.Size)
{
   chartArea1.AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
   chartArea1.AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = false;
}
```

So when you added points more than your scaleview - scrollbar is appear

Answer (score 0):

I worked out my own way for that. Hope it helps you:

1. Add your chart to a Panel.
2. Set the AutoScroll property of the panel to true with `panelName.AutoScroll=true;`
3. Size the chart properly in the panel.
4. You can now use the panel's scrollbar as if it were the chart's!
5. If data gets added continuously(e.g. with a timer or so), add this to the timer's tick event:

   `chartName.Size = new Size(width++, height++);` where `int width = chartName.Width;` and `int height = chartName.Height;`