# MS-Chart Zooming of x-axis with scroll bar in c#

Tags: c#, mschart

I have added the scroll bar to the x-axis of my mschart control using this link [Adding a scroll bar to MS Chart control C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141126/adding-a-scroll-bar-to-ms-chart-control-c/5146430#5146430) and it worked as expected. But now my requirement is, I need zooming for both the axis. But since I removed Zoom reset button for x-axis, I have used the following to reset it by forcing.

```
private void chart1_AxisScrollBarClicked(object sender, ScrollBarEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle zoom reset button
    if(e.ButtonType == ScrollBarButtonType.ZoomReset)        
    {
        // Event is handled, no more processing required
        e.IsHandled = true;

        // Reset zoom on X and Y axis
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
    }
  }
```

But it is not working properly. Please help me in fixing this in c#..

Comment: "is not working properly" is too vague... how it doesn't work ?

Comment: I need to have zooming for both axis. So I tried resetting both the axis when the y-axis zoom reset is clicked in the "chart1_AxisScrollBarClicked(object sender, ScrollBarEventArgs e)" event (since x-axis zoom reset has been disabled). Now Y-axis is working fine but x-axis is not resetting back to the initial view.

Comment: I have tried to give you an answer... let me know if you still have problems

Answer (score 4):

Try using `ZoomReset(0)`.

```
private void zeroZoom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset(0);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first thing coming in mind, is that your problem is related to multiple zooming.

As you had noticed, by default the zoom-reset button (exactly like the ZoomReset method) doesn't reset the zoom completely, but restore the previous view-status, i.e. if you have zoomed more than one time, it returns just to the previous zoomed view.

To completely reset the zoom, you can use this code:

```
while (chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.IsZoomed)
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset();

while (chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.IsZoomed)
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
```

Conversely, if you like the default zoom-reset behaviour, you should have two buttons for the two axis because it's possible to have different number of view-statex for the different axis.

Another possibility, is that you are zooming a secondary axis, like `AxisX2` or `AxisY2` (not sure, but I think that is depending on the chart type), so you should reset those (or, to be safe, just reset all axis...).

Comment: Thanks for responding immediately.The Y-axis should reset to the default view but the x-axis should reset to the initial view ie.chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0,10); But if I use your suggested code, the X-axis is resetting to a view without scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the below code today and it seems like working fine. Here the for loop handles the X axis with scroll and the next if block handles the ordinary X-axis. Could you please have a glance at it and let me know your views about it?

```
private void chart1_AxisScrollBarClicked(object sender, ScrollBarEventArgs e)
{
  Boolean blnIsXaxisReset = false;
  try
  {
    // Handle zoom reset button
    if(e.ButtonType == ScrollBarButtonType.ZoomReset)        
    {
      // Event is handled, no more processing required
      e.IsHandled = true;

      // Reset zoom on Y axis
      while (chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.IsZoomed)
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset();

      //Handles Zoom reset on X axis with scroll bar
      foreach (Series series in chart1.Series)
      {
        if (series.YAxisType == AxisType.Secondary)
        {
          chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(-10, 10);
          blnIsXaxisReset = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      //Handles Zoom reset on ordinary X axis
      if (blnIsXaxisReset == false)
      {
        while (chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.IsZoomed)
          chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    BuildException buildException = new BuildException();
    buildException.SystemException = ex;
    buildException.CustomMessage = "Error in zooming the Chart";
    ExceptionHandler.HandleException(buildException);
  }
}
```

Thanks for your effort!!