# Show certain number of datapoints on chart at a time

Tags: winforms, charts

I'm new to charting in winforms and I'm having a little trouble getting the chart to display a set number of points at time.

Using the code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5146430 :

```
private void FillChart()
{
    int blockSize = 100;

    // generates random data (i.e. 30 * blockSize random numbers)
    Random rand = new Random();
    var valuesArray = Enumerable.Range(0, blockSize * 30).Select(x => rand.Next(1, 10)).ToArray();

    // clear the chart
    chart1.Series.Clear();

    // fill the chart
    var series = chart1.Series.Add("My Series");
    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
    for (int i = 0; i < valuesArray.Length; i++)
        series.Points.AddXY(i, valuesArray[i]);
    var chartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea];

    // set view range to [0,max]
    chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = valuesArray.Length;

    // enable autoscroll
    chartArea.CursorX.AutoScroll = true;

    // let's zoom to [0,blockSize] (e.g. [0,100])
    chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
    chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
    int position = 0;
    int size = blockSize;
    chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(position, size);

    // disable zoom-reset button (only scrollbar's arrows are available)
    chartArea.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;

    // set scrollbar small change to blockSize (e.g. 100)
    chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = blockSize;
}
```

What would I change here to only show, say three data points at a time? I tried changing the `Maximum` of the x-axis, which worked but took away the scrolling bar. I also tried messing around with the `blockSize` variable here.

Comment: Try `chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(position, size * 2)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This just seemed to double the amount of points shown.